# Adding new element to array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a store in java and I'm trying to add a new item to an array, but I can't figure out how to make it work. `add.items(i);` won't work because that's only for `ArrayList`, and a requirement for this task is that I have to use an array. The purpose of this function is it checks if there is an empty space in the array, which has a maximum size of 10, and it adds an item if it's not full.

```
public boolean addItem (Item i){
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i] == null) {
            add.items(i);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `add.items(i);` won't work for an ArrayList either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work because you are using duplicate variables `i`.

Try this instead:

```
public boolean addItem (Item item) {
    // Rename loop variable
    for (int x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
        if (items[x] == null) {
            // Asign the incoming item to items array in case this position is empty
            items[x] = item;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to move that `return false` one level later... otherwise it will never get beyond the first iteration of the loop

Comment: May I suggest renaming `i` to `item` for improved readability. One letter variable names are only ok in for loops and similar.